# In C# is it possible to determine if a variable has an enumerator

Tags: c#, enumeration

I am trying to write a generic comparison routine.  However, some of the items in my class are in Collections and I need to enumerate to compare.

Is there an easy way, without a try/catch block to determine is a variable supports GetEnumerator()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers suggesting you check to see if the object is an `IEnumerable` are reasonably spot on. It's going to be the case the overwhelming majority of the time that your collection or object will implement that interface if it supports enumeration. But it is not required.

For something to be enumerated in a `foreach`, it really only needs to expose a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an object with suitable `MoveNext()` and `Current` implementations. Consider something like:

```
class CustomCollection
{
    public CustomEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CustomEnumerator();
    }
}

class CustomEnumerator
{
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return (++this.Current <= 10);
    }

    public int Current { get; private set; }
}
```

You can put `new CustomCollection()` into a loop and get the values 1..10.

By all means, check for the interface first. If that's all you want to support, fine. If you want to go that extra mile, you'd need to perform steps like the compiler would, as in check for the appropriate methods and return types. Here's a *thoroughly untested draft* of an implementation.

```
bool IsEnumerable(object obj)
{
    if (obj is IEnumerable)
        return true;

    var info = obj.GetType().GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
    if (info != null)
    {
        if (info.ReturnType != null)
        {
            var moveNextMethod = info.ReturnType.GetMethod("MoveNext");
            if (moveNextMethod != null && moveNextMethod.ReturnType == typeof(bool))
            {
                var currentProperty = info.ReturnType.GetProperty("Current");
                if (currentProperty != null)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Some quick tests in LinqPad, but by no means exhaustive...

```
IsEnumerable(new CustomCollection()).Dump(); // true
IsEnumerable(1).Dump(); // false 
IsEnumerable(new List<int>()).Dump(); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (object is IEnumerable)
{
    foreach(var value in (IEnumerable)object)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast it into `IEnumerable`:

```
var list = someVariable as IEnumerable;
if (list != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetEnumerator()` is defined on the `IEnumerable` interface, so:

```
if (obj is IEnumerable) 
{ 
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it implements `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable`, so any generic collection implements `IEnumerable` too.

if you have a type you can use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` if you have an instance you can use the `is`/`as` operators.

Answer (score 0):

The `IEnumerable` interface determines whether or not something is enumerable.

Comment: Usually, yes. But it's not required.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Out of curiosity, what are the other cases?

Comment: @sixfeetsix, you can include any object in a `foreach` as long as it exposes a method called `GetEnumerator` that returns a suitable object that has a `bool MoveNext()` method and `Current` property.

Comment: @sixfeetsix, see section 8.8.4 of the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) if this interests you.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: well that's interesting; tried it for myself and indeed it works; it then logically follows that all 6 answers currently posted including mine are incorrect. Feel free to post your answer and you'll then have my vote!

Comment: @Anthony: In practice, you typically find that objects that implement pattern-based enumerators *also* implement interface-based enumerators. The interface version may incur a gc pressure penalty or a boxing penalty, so it might be slightly less efficient. But it is quite rare for an object to *only* support pattern-based enumeration these days.

Comment: @Eric, absolutely, I personally wouldn't think of doing the pattern without the interface.

Comment: @Anthony As mentioned in other questions, the main reason for pattern based seems to be .net 1.0's lack of generics which would make an Interface impossible without boxing value types (since the return type would be object).

Comment: @Michael: Correct, that is one reason. The other reason is that if you make the enumerator a mutable value type then you can avoid collection pressure. In some scenarios it is important to minimize collection pressure, even if that means doing a "worst practice" like writing a mutable value type.

Comment: @Eric Ah, true. I remember a lot of articles about Iterators and XNA on the Xbox 360 and avoiding collection pressure at any price.